# Why indexing .SD with a number is faster than when the number is stored in a variable

Tags: r, performance, data.table, subset

I have a data.table that I want to aggregate by group (customer ID) and look at how their first spend compares to the second spend, third spend etc.

Select e.g. the first row by group using `.SD[1]`:

```
agg_dt <- dt[ , .SD[1], by = customer_id]
```

gives a really quick result (1.94 seconds for a dataset with 5 million + rows).

However, if I put the index number (here 1) into a variable (which I want to do so that I can turn this into a function that I can call repeatedly with different numbers) it suddenly goes much slower (5.23 MINUTES).

```
number_var <- 1
agg_dt <- dt[ , .SD[number_var], by = customer_id]
```

As far as I am concerned using a number directly and using a number via a variable should make no difference, so what is causing this and how can I fix it?

To show the code fully, I have made a toy example on kaggle:

https://www.kaggle.com/code/keithcooper/data-table-weird-result/notebook

It is much smaller, but even there the difference is 0.00995 secs to 2.71042 secs.

Comment: Use `verbose = TRUE` in `[.data.table` and you will find that `d[ , .SD[1], by = g, verbose = TRUE]` is GForce optimized, whereas `d[ , .SD[ix], by = g, verbose = TRUE]` is not. See also `?datatable.optimize`.

Comment: That looks like the right answer. I am taking from the reading that there is not way for me to fix this and I will just need to work around it. Is that correct?

Comment: I reckon a first step would be to avoid `.SD[ix]` and instead use `.I[ix]`, to improve performance of your immediate issue. However, when you write "_how their first spend compares to the second spend, third spend etc._" I get a nagging feeling of an XY-problem and that your overall task may be solved differently, rather than creating (several) subsets of your data ;) Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indexing `.SD` with a number is "GForce optimized", whereas indexing with the number stored in a variable is not optimized.

This can be verified by setting `verbose = TRUE` ("turns on status and information messages to the console")

```
library(data.table)
d = data.table(g = rep(1:2, each = 2), v = 1:4)
```

For each group, index `.SD` with a number, e.g. 1:

```
d[ , .SD[1], by = g, verbose = TRUE]
#...snip... 
# lapply optimization changed j from '.SD[1]' to 'list(v[1])'
# GForce optimized j to 'list(`g[`(v, 1))'
# Making each group and running j (GForce TRUE)
#...snip...
#    g v
# 1: 1 1
# 2: 2 3
```

Index `.SD` with a number stored in a variable

```
ix = 1
d[ , .SD[ix], by = g, verbose = TRUE]
#...snip...
# lapply optimization is on, j unchanged as '.SD[ix]'
# GForce is on, left j unchanged
# Old mean optimization is on, left j unchanged.
# Making each group and running j (GForce FALSE) ... The result of j is a named list.
# It's very inefficient to create the same names over and over again for each group.
```

Performance can be improved considerably by using `.I[ix]` instead. However, neither that operation is GForce optimized.

```
d[d[, .I[ix], by = g, verbose = TRUE]$V1]
#...snip...
# lapply optimization is on, j unchanged as '.I[ix]'
# GForce is on, left j unchanged
# Old mean optimization is on, left j unchanged.
# Making each group and running j (GForce FALSE)
```

---

As noted by @jangorecki, in the development version of `data.table` (`>= v. 1.14.7`), the `env` argument can be used (here `env = list(ix = ix)`). Then GForce is optimized also when the index is stored in a variable.

```
# data.table::update_dev_pkg()
library(data.table)
# data.table 1.14.7 IN DEVELOPMENT
```

Indexing `.SD`:

```
d[ , .SD[ix], by = g, env = list(ix = ix), verbose = TRUE]
#...snip...
# lapply optimization changed j from '.SD[1]' to 'list(v[1])'
# GForce optimized j to 'list(`g[`(v, 1))'
# Making each group and running j (GForce TRUE)
```

Indexing `.I`:

```
d[d[, .I[ix], by = g, env = list(ix = ix), verbose = TRUE]$V1]
#...snip...
# lapply optimization is on, j unchanged as '.I[1]'
# GForce optimized j to '`g[`(.I, 1)'
# Making each group and running j (GForce TRUE)
```

---

See also `?datatable.optimize`.